# Поразрядный сдвиг чисел

Tags: c, операторы

Требуется написать программу, выполняющую поразрядный сдвиг десятичного числа  влево с выводом его двоичного представления с заданным количеством повторений. Написал такую программу, которая работает, но при больших значениях двоичный эквивалент выводится неправильно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

unsigned long int decbin(unsigned long a);
void shift(unsigned long var, unsigned int m, unsigned int n);
int main ()
{
unsigned long long a;
unsigned int s, r;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

printf("Введите число: ");
    scanf("%ld", &a);

printf("Введите величину сдвига: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);

printf("Введите количество повторений: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);

shift(a, s, r);
getchar();
return 0; 
}

unsigned long int decbin(unsigned long a)
{
    if (a/2 == 0)
    {
    return a % 2;
    }
return decbin(a/2)*10 + a % 2;
}

void shift(unsigned long var, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
printf("Введенное число: %ld\n", var);
printf("Двоичное представление: %ld\n", decbin(var));
decbin(var);
printf("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
  {
     var = var << x;
     printf("Следующее число: %ld\n", var);
     printf("Двоичное представление: %ld\n", decbin(var));
     printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Большие значения это какие? Что на входе, что на выходе и что должно быть допишите прямо в вопрос. Что вы узнали о работе программы при использовании отладчика?

Comment: @e2e4 Что такое "величина сдвига" и "количество повторений"? Какой смысл в этих двух отдельных значениях?

Comment: @e2e4 Вам для представления в двоичном виде в качестве выходного значения надо использовать символьный массив, а не число. Иначе просто не хватит десятичных разрядов числа, чтобы вывести двоичное представление.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow прощу прощение за косноязычие, но насколько я понял из формулировки задания, величина сдвига, определяет на сколько разрядов исходное число сдвигается влево, а количество повторений определяет сколько раз будет происходить сдвиг влево на n (в программе - переменная s) разрядов.

Comment: опоздал с ответом ровно на минуту :( :)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам, вот код, кому надо.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <locale.h>
 #include <malloc.h>
 #include <string.h>

  void decbin(int x);
  void shift(int var, unsigned int x, unsigned int y);
  int main ()
  {
  int a;
  unsigned int s, r;
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

  printf("Введите число: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Введите величину сдвига: ");
  scanf("%d", &s);

  printf("Введите количество повторений: ");
  scanf("%d", &r);

  shift(a, s, r);
  getchar();
  return 0; 
  } 


void decbin(int x)
{
char *t = (char*)malloc(100);
int i = 0;
do
{
    t[i++] = x % 2 + '0';
    x = x / 2;
} 
while (x != 0);
t[i] = '\0';
int k = strlen(t);

for (int i = k; i > 0; i--)
printf("%c", t[i]); 

}



 void shift(int var, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
 printf("Введенное число: %d\n", var);
 printf("Двоичное представление: ");
 decbin(var);
 printf("\n");

 for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
 {
 var = var << x;
 printf("Следующее число: %d\n", var);
 printf("Двоичное представление: ");
 decbin(var);
 printf("\n");
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

long и так хранится в бинарном виде, вопрос только в отображении его в нужной системе счисления - по умолчанию он отображается в десятичной. Используйте itoa для перевода в строковую запись в нужной системе:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long int decbin(unsigned long a);
void shift(unsigned long var, unsigned int m, unsigned int n);
int main()
{
    unsigned long long a;
    unsigned int s, r;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    printf("Введите число: ");
    scanf("%ld", &a);

    printf("Введите величину сдвига: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);

    printf("Введите количество повторений: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);

    shift(a, s, r);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void shift(unsigned long var, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    char buffer[33];

    printf("Введенное число: %ld\n", var);
    itoa(var, buffer, 2);
    printf("Двоичное представление: %s\n", buffer);

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        var = var << x;
        printf("Следующее число: %ld\n", var);

        itoa(var, buffer, 2);
        printf("Двоичное представление: %s\n", buffer);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```